# In Practical Magic, why did only one sister have gifts?

Tags: practical-magic

In the movie Practical Magic, and I think in the book too, every pair of sisters had an innately gifted sister and then a sister that needed to put forth extra effort to practice magic.

Why didn't both sisters have magical gifts?

Comment: Are RomComs in-scope? :)

Comment: I think the magic is integral enough to the story for it to count as fantasy.

Answer (score 3):

In the movie, at least, both sisters had the magic.  Sally (Sandra Bullock) quit using hers after her husband was killed by the curse, until her sister and aunts prodded her into it again.

Comment: I know they both had the gift, but in all three of the pairs of sisters that were in the movie, it showed that one had a lot higher magical abilities than the other one. Sandra Bullock's character didn't need to do a lot of the prep work that Nicole Kidman's character needed to do. Same for the aunts and lesser so for the daughters.